# How should the "first month of each quarteryear" be represented using joda-time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm working on some accounting logic. The logic is that an accounting that happened in the first month of a quarter year must have a value date that is at the end of the preceding quarter year. I know that I can represent the month as a period. But I have no idea how to represent the recurring period of a quarter year.

I'm able to do the calculation using joda-time classes that would give me the value date at the end of the preceding quarter year. However I would like to represent "first month of each quarter year" as a single value that I use in my calculations.

So is there some API in joda-time that is well suitable for representing this kind of recurring period?

Some example dates are:

```
date of invoce | value date  
2013-01-01     | 2012-12-31  
2013-01-31     | 2012-12-31  
2013-02-01     | 2013-02-01  
2013-03-31     | 2013-03-31  
2013-04-01     | 2013-03-31
```

OK, here is more explanative example as requested in comments:
The accounting logic is about a kind of pension funds you have to apply for. You apply for the pensions of 2012 in the succeeding year, exactly on 1st of January 2013. It will be granted to you on the 15th of April 2013. Since April is the first month of the quarter year, the granting will have its value date set to the 31st of March. All pensions that are accounted within one quarter year are paid 1 month and 5 days after that quarter year has ended. So even if you have been granted your pension in April, you will still get it paid on 5th of May. Otherwise you would have to wait for it to be payed until 5th of September.

But I don't really know how this example should help. This question really is about modeling "every first month of each quarter year" with joda-time classes or even implementing some API of joda-time.

Comment: can you explain your question with a scenario using actual month and year in example case??

Comment: By example i meant, a scenario like, suppose if current date is 2013-12-11 , the the result you want is the date of last year january?? something like this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Algorithm

You need to write a routine where you pass in a date and get back a date representing the last day of previous quarter. Indeed, that sounds like a good name for the method, and a better summary of your problem: `endingDateOfPreviousQuarter( someDate )`.

Or alternatively named, in my own naming convention where I use `start` and `stop` to mean inclusive rather than exclusive boundary, `stopDateOfPreviousQuarter( someDate )`.

I would do that with a pair of methods.

`startDateOfQuarter( someDate )`

1. Extract the month of the passed date by calling [monthOfYear()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#monthOfYear%28%29).
2. Determine which quarter is that month (test for being between 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, 9-12).
3. Get start date of that quarter (as seen in code below, passing year & month & dayOfMonth to constructor).

`stopDateOfPreviousQuarter( someDate )`

1. Call "startDateOfQuarter" method, passing the date in question.
2. On the start date returned, call the Joda-Time method [minusDays(1)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays%28int%29).

Voilà, you have the date of the last day in the previous quarter.

The main idea here is that generally it is better to **find the beginning of a time element**, and then use `minus`, rather than trying to directly get the ending point. Get the beginning of an hour, day, week, month, or quarter. This avoids problems with leap days, leap seconds†, [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST), errors in remembering which months have 30 vs 31 days, and the problem of fractional seconds with varying resolution making it difficult to determine the very end of an hour or day. Furthermore, focusing on beginning of periods brings clarity to thinking about date-times, at least in my experience.

### Info

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) does not recognize quarters. Some people extend the spec to do so, using a "Q" combined with some identifier, as mentioned in [this wiki](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/ISO_8601).

[Joda-Time 2](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) does not support quarters, as mentioned in [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/joda-time/discussion/337835/thread/79259c3c/) in 2011.

ISO 8601 defines precisely a definition of 52 or 53 [numbered weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates). Joda-Time supports that concept, asrepresented by the [weekOfWeekYear](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/field.html#weekOfWeekyear). Some businesses define their quarters by a subset of that 1 to 52/53 range.

Or you could define your quarters by the end of the 3rd, 6th, 9th, and 12th months of the year. Joda-Time has constructors for DateTime class that lets you specify a month number. Note the use of the method [withTimeAtStartOfDay()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) to let Joda-Time do the work of getting the first moment of the day as not all days in all time zones have a midnight.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone parisDateTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
org.joda.time.DateTime q1Start =  new org.joda.time.DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, parisDateTimeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
org.joda.time.DateTime q2Start =  new org.joda.time.DateTime(2013, 4, 1, 0, 0, parisDateTimeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();

System.out.println( "Q1 begins in Paris FR: " + q1Start );
System.out.println( "Q2 begins in Paris FR: " + q2Start );

// When querying a database or comparing items in a collection to find Q1 data, 
// Look for: (GreaterThanOrEqualTo q1Start) AND (LessThan q2Start)
```

---

If you absolutely want dates only without any time-of-day element, use the Joda-Time’s [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class. That class sports a [minusDays()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays%28int%29) method just like [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class.

---

By the way, consider whether you are dealing with simple dates (without times) or date-time. You may think, for example that invoices use only simple dates, but actually they are often stamped upon receipt with a clock machine that includes a time which may need to be recorded for legal and audit reasons. Also, usually databases store date values as date-time based in UTC (with no time zone offset).

---

† Joda-Time ignores [leap-seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), but my point still stands.

Comment: I'm using `LocalDate` for representing the time points in this accounting logic. At least in the portion I'm currently working on times are of no use. But thanks for advice on that.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker The ideas and code in my answer apply to `LocalDate` as well as `DateTime`. The "LocalDate" class has a minusDays() method, as does "DateTime".

Answer (score 8):

I had to implement this too. Here is an implementation that seems ok at first glance.

```
public class QuarterPeriods {

    public static LocalDate quarterStartFor(LocalDate date) {
        return date.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonthOfYear((((date.getMonthOfYear() - 1) / 3) * 3) + 1);
    }

    public static LocalDate quarterEndFor(LocalDate date) {
        return quarterStartFor(date).plusMonths(3).minusDays(1);
    }
}

public class QuarterPeriodsTest {

    @Test
    public void startOfQuarter() throws Exception {
        assertThat(quarterStartFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/02/02")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/01/01")));
        assertThat(quarterStartFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/01/01")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/01/01")));
        assertThat(quarterStartFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/02/02")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/01/01")));
        assertThat(quarterStartFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/04/01")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/04/01")));
        assertThat(quarterStartFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/07/01")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/07/01")));
        assertThat(quarterStartFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/12/19")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/10/01")));
    }

    @Test
    public void endOfQuarter() throws Exception {
        assertThat(quarterEndFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/02/02")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/03/31")));
        assertThat(quarterEndFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/01/01")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/03/31")));
        assertThat(quarterEndFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/02/02")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/03/31")));
        assertThat(quarterEndFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/04/01")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/06/30")));
        assertThat(quarterEndFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/07/01")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/09/30")));
        assertThat(quarterEndFor(StubDates.dateOf("2011/12/19")), equalTo(StubDates.dateOf("2011/12/31")));
    }
}

public class StubDates {

    public static LocalDate dateOf(String date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime(date).toLocalDate();
    }
}
```